# How can I verify if a user exists in database mongodb using node.js and angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I've just to check if a user already exists on my back-end and show in my front-end. I need to create other api function to do this ? Please, help me. I'm a beginner in MEAN apps.

It's my controller of my form:

```
angular.module('sun').controller('UsersController', function($scope, $http, $location){
    $scope.mensage = {};
    $scope.user = {}; 
    $scope.submit = function() { 
       if($scope.form.$valid) {
       var promisse = $http.post('/v1/users', $scope.user)
            promisse.then(function(rt){
                $scope.user = rt.data;
                $location.path('/users');
                $scope.mensage = 'Congrats!';
                $scope.user = {};            
       }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            $scope.mensage = 'Failed';
       });
     }             
 };
});
```

It's my back-end:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var api = {};
var model = mongoose.model('User');

api.add = function (req, res) {
    var user = request.body;

    model.create(user)
        .then(function (user) {
            response.json(user);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            response.status(500).json(error);
        });
};
module.exports = api;
```

Comment: this is pretty basic, have you looked into any tutorials or documentation of mongoose ? try looking there you will find plenty examples and information.

Comment: You really need to take advantage of postman for this.  Generally I test all of my routes in express with it before connecting to my services.  https://www.getpostman.com/docs/blog_mentions.  Also put a break point above your promise and step into it.  you should have a good sense at that point.

Comment: I've done. It was very simple. Thank you guys!